# Is it valid HTML to store an image inside of an HTML file?

Tags: css, image, html, styles

Such as:

```
<img style="width:500px;height:150px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH)" />
```

The application I have displays an authorization letter, and then displays a canvas.  The canvas allows touch/mouse events and the user is able to sign their name to it.  Then the HTML and the signature are saved.  The customer is requesting that these be saved to one single file so that they don't get mismatched signature PNG files and HTML text files in the future.

So, while I don't like the look of this approach, it seems to work fine in Chrome and even IE, and it solves the customers request of only having to store one single file with the signed authorization.

My question is - Is this legal HTML or is Chrome being nice to me?

Comment: Just see [http://validator.w3.org/](http://validator.w3.org/) for any question of HTML validity.  AFAIK, to be valid HTML, `src` and `alt` attributes are **mandatory**.  As far as what you posted, if you're going to use a CSS background image, why even bother to use a `img` tag?  Just make it a `div`.

Comment: How do you know it isn't an actual image where the background-image isn't some sort of funky frame that can't be recreated with CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

```
<img style="width:500px;height:150px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH)" />
```

*"My question is - Is this legal HTML?"*

---

No.  According to [the W3C HTML spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-img-element.html#attr-img-src), the `src` attribute *"must be present"*.

Why not change your `img` into a `div`?

```
<div style="width:500px;height:150px;background:url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH)"></div>
```

In general, any question regarding HTML validity should be put through the online validator before coming to SO:  http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thanks for the HTML spec as well as the alternate DIV approach.  I will check the w3 site from here on in.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is not [valid](http://validator.w3.org/). But if you dig a bit you'll find references to the [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) in the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/objects.html):

```
<OBJECT id="clock1"
        classid="clsid:663C8FEF-1EF9-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502"
        data="data:application/x-oleobject;base64, ...base64 data...">
    A clock.
</OBJECT>
```

... so the problem is not the `data:` uri. As for whether this is a chrome-only thing, [the Wikipedia article on the Data URI Scheme contains a section devoted to browser support.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support)

It looks like the CSS is not valid either. The following fails validation on the [w3c CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input):

```
.wtv {
    background:url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH);
    color:red;
}
```

The validator gives the following error:

```
Value Error : background url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH) is an incorrect URL url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH)
```

So what you're doing works, but according to the letter of the law, it is not *valid*.

Comment: I am strictly supporting HTML5.  Not sure if that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine in my opinion. Having actual base64 image data in a CSS declaration is fine. Interesting approach if the output of the process is just an HTML file.

Comment: Please explain.  According to [the W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-img-element.html#attr-img-src), the `src` attribute _"must be present"_.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the question would be if this is valid CSS. However, it can be used in both and should be valid. But be careful, not all browsers support it.

[Wikipedia: Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)

Comment: Regarding the OP's question about valid HTML... according to [the W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-img-element.html#attr-img-src), the `src` attribute _"must be present"_.

Comment: Is it valid CSS? I tried validating that property/value and got `Value Error : background url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH) is an incorrect URL url(data:image/png;base64,BLAH)`

Comment: Good question. Take in consideration, that W3C validator might not support everything, jet ... - We may need to read up on this.

Comment: @hm - Except that the w3c defines the specs, and consequently what's valid. "Valid" in the sense of validation - not in the sense of "it works!"

Comment: @Richard no doubt about that. I was talking about the validation software, which may not be perfect. With "reading up on this", I ment the W3C specifications.